# How can I access a component's ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form) to create a form from a JSON schema. In [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/v4dhkku7/1/), I've created a form that consists of a single `<input type="file">` field.

An instance of a [FileWidget](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/blob/master/src/components/widgets/FileWidget.js) component is used to render this field, and as you can see in [the source code](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/blob/master/src/components/widgets/FileWidget.js#L98), this stores a ref to the `<input>` element in `this.inputRef`.

I would like to use this ref to add additional attributes to the input field, but I can't figure out how to access the ref from the `componentDidMount` method of `MyForm`?

The source code of the component in the JSFiddle example is:

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);   
    this.uiSchema = {};
    this.schema = {
      "title": "Files",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "file": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "data-url",
          "title": "Single file"
        },
      }
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // How can I get access to the FileWidget's inputRef property here?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form    
        schema={this.schema} 
        uiSchema={this.uiSchema}
        liveValidate />
    )
  }
};
```

Comment: Manipulate the input field how? React-style thinking suggests you should do it from "above" - i.e. from inside `MyForm`. `formContext` might be useful: https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form#the-formcontext-object

Comment: @Adam I want to add additional attributes to the `<input type="file">` element

Comment: This is not recommended to access internal variables of nested components, why can't you use the schema to add properties you need?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk the documentation says: 

"The included FileWidget exposes a reference to the <input type="file" /> element node as an inputRef component property.

This allows you to programmatically trigger the browser's file selector which can be used in a custom file widget."

So it appears that the authors of `FileWidget` are expecting you to access this reference https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form#file-widget-input-ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import and use `FileWidget` from the same library to get a ref on it:

```
import FileWidget from 'react-jsonschema-form/lib/components/widgets/FileWidget'

constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.widgets = {
    FileWidget: (props) => (
      <FileWidget
        {...props}
        ref={ref => {
          this.fileWidget = ref;
        }}
      />
    )
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.fileWidget.inputRef);
}

<Form widgets={this.widgets} ... />
```

[image: Edit oq7xqoz46q]

#### Sidenote:

This is not a very intuitive way for a library to expose an internal ref. It should have been:

```
<input
  ref={ref => {
    if (this.props.setInputRef) {
      this.props.setInputRef(ref);
    }
  }}
/>
```

Then you could get `inputRef` with

```
<FileWidget setInputRef={ref => { this.inputRef = ref } ... />
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/ajuc8yo8/1/
Presumably the reason it doesn't work is because `inputRef` is a property of the `FileWidget`, not a property of the `Form`.

Comment: Didn't notice you are not rendering `FileWidget` directly. See if my above code works.

Comment: That looks perfect, thanks a lot. I didn't realise you could use a function as a value in the `widgets` object.