# Show/hide a spinner when file upload starts/finishes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [this React component](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/blob/master/src/components/widgets/FileWidget.js) to upload files to the browser (not to a server). This component is part of the [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/) library, so I can't change the source code. The `render` method of this component is shown below

```
  render() {
    const { multiple, id, readonly, disabled, autofocus } = this.props;
    const { filesInfo } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <input
            ref={ref => (this.inputRef = ref)}
            id={id}
            type="file"
            disabled={readonly || disabled}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            defaultValue=""
            autoFocus={autofocus}
            multiple={multiple}
          />
        </p>
        <FilesInfo filesInfo={filesInfo} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This component accepts one or more files as input, base64 encodes them, and stores the encoded files in memory.

However, if the user chooses a large file (e.g. 5MB), there's a noticeable delay while processing. I would like to show a spinner when this processing starts and hide it when it finishes, but I can't find the relevant events on which to show/hide the spinner.

In case it's relevant, I have a `ref` to the widget, and can use this to get a `ref` to the `<input>` field via `myWidgetRef.inputRef`.

Comment: Are you looking for [File API events](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/22/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-3/)?

Comment: @AlexW I don't think that will help me, because I've no way to access the `FileReader` object, because it's not exported by the `FileWidget.js` module

Comment: Can you please provide jsFiddle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event listener to the input ref, which will be called when a file is selected.

> onChange function passed as a prop is only called when the upload is finished

Then use the `onChange` prop for handling processing completion.

[image: Edit n5vk9z426p]

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";
import FileWidget from "react-jsonschema-form/lib/components/widgets/FileWidget";

class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      processing: false
    };
    this.inputChanged = this.inputChanged.bind(this);
  }

  inputChanged() {
    console.log("processing");
    this.setState({ processing: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fileWidget.inputRef.addEventListener("change", this.inputChanged);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.fileWidget.inputRef.removeEventListener("change", this.inputChanged);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>Is processing: {this.state.processing + ""}</div>
        <Form
          schema={{
            type: "object",
            properties: {
              file: {
                type: "string",
                format: "data-url"
              }
            }
          }}
          widgets={{
            FileWidget: props => (
              <FileWidget
                {...props}
                ref={ref => {
                  this.fileWidget = ref;
                }}
                onChange={() => {
                  console.log("processed");
                  this.setState({ processing: false });
                }}
              />
            )
          }}
          liveValidate
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: For those wondering how the large chunk of code not in OP come about, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066621/how-can-i-access-a-components-ref/50072177#50072177

Comment: FYI, usage of the `componentWill*` lifecycle methods is discouraged https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Comment: Only `componentWillMount` is discouraged (because the correct way is to do it in `constructor`/`componentDidMount`), `componentWillUnmount` remains an essential and irreplaceable part of the React lifecycle. If you look at the examples in that article, the recommended way still includes `componentWillUnmount`.

Answer (score 3):

```
onChange = () => {
    this.setState({uploading: true})
    //upload fetch call
   fetch().then(results => {//this is dummy call
     this.setState({uploading: false})
   })
}

render() {
    const { multiple, id, readonly, disabled, autofocus } = this.props;
    const { filesInfo } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
        {this.state.uploading ? <div className="progress"></div> : null}
          <input
            ref={ref => (this.inputRef = ref)}
            id={id}
            type="file"
            disabled={readonly || disabled}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            defaultValue=""
            autoFocus={autofocus}
            multiple={multiple}
          />
        </p>
        <FilesInfo filesInfo={filesInfo} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that this component is part of a library, so I can't change its source code

Comment: are you passing onChange Functionn with `FileWidget` component??

Comment: No, but looking at the source code it seems the `onChange` function passed as a prop is only called when the upload is finished

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you're processing this large file on client side.

So the simpliest solution for you will be to put loading flag before processing start and remove it after processing ends.

After you do this -  you will encounter that flag change doesn't reflected to DOM state, because rendering is deferred.

So the solution will be to convert code from:

```
setLoadingFlag();
doComputing();
removeLoadingFlag();
```

to async form:

```
setLoadingFlag();
setTimeout(() => {
    doComputing();
    removeLoadingFlag();
}, 0)
```

This will allow React to render loader

Comment: Also please use CSS sninner (not React) if you want to see animation

Comment: If you don't see spinner - try to increase timeout, then search for an reason why you don't see it in few ms.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

1. Use axios in react to also show percentage of file loading.
2. Create a simple html absolute loader with two styles of the element one will contain css:

display: block;

Another will contain:

```
display: none;
```

Give your loader element classname and change it with this.state so when you start uploading file you will change classname of loader element to one which contains styling of display block , then change it back to prvious when uploading done.

If you want full code drop me a message i have one.
[Rohan Girdhani](http://rohangirdhani.com)

Answer (score 0):

simplest way of doing this is got to main.html(the file which has your main container) and add an additional div like this. Note that this div is noting but an hcl css version of the spinner 

`<div class ="app-spinner" style="display: none" />`

Note that by default the spinner is hidden (display: none); Now define an utility method which will toggle spinner on and off. something like this

```
`
export const showLoader = (load) => {
load ? document.getElementsByClassName("app-spinner").style.display="block" : document.getElementsByClassName("app-spinner").style.display="none"
}
`
```

now all you have to do is import showLoader in the file whre you have input type file like this

```
`
import { showLoader } from "../pathWhereTheUtilityMethodIsDeclared"
`
```

Now go to the Input tag and add an onClick event and trigger the utility method like this Note we are not using onChange

```
<input
            ref={ref => (this.inputRef = ref)}
            id={id}
            type="file"
            disabled={readonly || disabled}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            onClick={()=>{showLoader(true)}}
            defaultValue=""
            autoFocus={autofocus}
            multiple={multiple}
          />
```

onClick={()=>{showLoader(true)}} will toggle on the hidden spinner and when the encoding to base64 is done just call the method with false showLoader(false) this will make sure that spinner is hidden. (Note make sure u import showloader before calling else u end up with undefined error)